# What superseded XYGraph.dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, visualization

I am trying to get some charting and visualizations going in F#. Unfortunately, the book I am using refers to a lot of .dll files that have been superseded with the advent of Windows 7. I am using Visual Studio 2010, F# 2.0.

What would be a useful replacement for "XYGraph.dll" for doing some simple graphs of mathematical functions?

Searching MSDN does not yield any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with "XYGraph.dll", so I'm not sure what were all the features that it had.

However, there is a MSDN section that discusses [Visualizing Data with .NET Charts in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273079.aspx). It covers .NET Chart Controls (available in .NET 4.0 and as a sperate download for .NET 3.5) and FSharpChart library, which is an F#-friendly wrapper for this library (as well as some other options like Excel).

The FSharpChart library seems to be the standard (and the easiest way) to visualize data from F#.

- The MSDN articles include [introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297116.aspx) and [visualization of financial data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297101.aspx).
- The [F# team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/04/15/getting-started-with-fsharpchart.aspx) also has a few articles about the library.
- Additional resources & downloads can be found in [Carl Nolan's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/06/22/fsharpchart-new-features-and-code-drop-availability.aspx) who has been contributing to the library and manages recent releases.

As far as I know, the only big limitation of .NET Chart Controls (and FSharpChart) is that they don't work in Silverlight. I'm not sure if that was supported by XYGraph.dll

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the new Data Visualization stuff in .NET 4. I described how to get a parametric plot in the blog post [here](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/07/f-vs-mathematica-parametric-plots.html).